# How can I parse data as json in node from orm database?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, json, orm

| date | month | total_employee | total_revenue | empName | emp_sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-26 | October | 2 | 620 | NameA | 620 |
| 2022-10-21 | October | 2 | 300 | NameA | 300 |
| 2022-10-21 | October | 2 | 290 | NameB | 290 |

This is a query that returns the data for daily total sales made by each employee...

when the data will go to front end as json data it needs to show like this -

```
{
    "date": "2022-10-26",
    "month": "October",
    "total_employee": 2,
    "total_revenue": 620.00,
    "total_sales":[ {"NameA": 620.00}]
  }
{
    "date": "2022-10-21",
    "month": "October",
    "total_employee": 2,
    "total_revenue": 590.00,
    "total_sales":[{"NameA": 300.00},{"NameB": 290.00}]
  }
```

the same date rows must merge together like in the total_sales and in the total_revenue it must add all the total sales done that day . how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an array that receives this merged data. You could something like the following:

```
const frontEndData = [];

databaseData.map(el => {
   const existingFeData = frontEndData.find(fed => fed.date === el.date)
   if (existingFeData) {
      // merge together with the existing on the array
   } else {
      // create a new entry on the array
   }
})
```

Now the code depends if you want to analyse by month/year or both...

Comment: This does need to sort by daily(last 30 days) and monthly(last 12 months)